# transform scale não funciona com esperado

Tags: css3

Quero aumentar o tamanho de uma certa parte do grafico ao passar com o rato (hover). Experimentei o transform mas não me funciona muito bem.

exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/tttxfvcu/10/

Comment: Qual o problema exatamente? O tamanho das fatias do gráfico aumentam em `hover`.

Comment: Sim aumentaram mas deslocaram-se. Não queria que saissem da sua posição

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você deve usar a propriededade `transform-origin`, note que é necessário definir `transform` no elemento sem `:hover`, para que o navegador desfaça o efeito.

Conforme a resposta do @GabrielOshiro, você pode adicionar compatibilidade para navegadores mais antigos para o `transform-origin` também (quando estas propriedades eram experimentais usando o prefixo `-moz` e `-webkit`)

> Recomendo ler: [É necessário adicionar prefixos em algumas propriedades do CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3674/3635)

Exemplo:

```
path {
          -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
       -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
            -o-transform: scale(1.0);
               transform: scale(1.0);
        transform-origin: center center;
   -moz-transform-origin: center center;
-webkit-transform-origin: center center;
}


path:hover {
          opacity: 0.8;
   -moz-transform: scale(1.1); 
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
     -o-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Você também pode adicionar um efeito animado usando `transition`, exemplo:

```css
#test {
        background-color: #f00;
                   width: 100px;
                  height: 100px;
          -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
       -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
            -o-transform: scale(1.0);
               transform: scale(1.0);
        transform-origin: center center;
   -moz-transform-origin: center center;
-webkit-transform-origin: center center;
         -moz-transition: transform 0.5s ease;
      -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease;
              transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

#test:hover {
          opacity: 0.8;
   -moz-transform: scale(1.1); 
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
     -o-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

### z-index e SVG

O SVG aparemente não muda a posição com `z-index`, então conforme está resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6585901/1518921) é necessário fazer o processo pelo javascript para reposicionar, usando `el.parentNode.appendChild(el);`, o problema é que o Raphael.js trabalha de modos diferentes em cada navegador, portanto teremos que usar as funções disponiveis para ele ao invés do CSS.

- `Raphael.toFront` irá fazer o efeito `z-index`
- `Raphael.animate` irá fazer o efeito semelhante ao do CSS

Exemplo:

```js
function efeitoHover(el) {
    el.mouseover(function () {
        el.toFront().animate({'opacity': '0.8', 'transform':"s1.1 1.1"}, 100);
    }).mouseout(function () {
        el.stop().animate({'transform': ""}, 50, "bounce");
    });
}

window.onload = function() {
    var data = [5,10,20,40,80,160,100];

    var color = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "gray","black"];

    var paper, arc;

    var sectorAngleArr = [];
    var total = 0;
    var startAngle = 0;
    var endAngle = 0;
    var x1, x2, y1, y2 = 0;

    paper = Raphael("holder"); //circle

    for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
        total += data[k];
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var angle = Math.ceil(360 * data[i] / total);
        sectorAngleArr.push(angle);
    }

    drawArcs();

    function drawArcs() {
        for (var i = 0; i < sectorAngleArr.length; i++) {
            startAngle = endAngle;
            endAngle = startAngle + sectorAngleArr[i];

            if(i == sectorAngleArr.length - 1) {  
                endAngle = 0;
            }

            x1 = parseInt(Math.round(200 + 195 * Math.cos(Math.PI * startAngle / 180)));
            y1 = parseInt(Math.round(200 + 195 * Math.sin(Math.PI * startAngle / 180)));

            x2 = parseInt(Math.round(200 + 195 * Math.cos(Math.PI * endAngle / 180)));
            y2 = parseInt(Math.round(200 + 195 * Math.sin(Math.PI * endAngle / 180)));

            var d = "M200,200  L" + x1 + "," + y1 + "  A195,195 0 " + ((endAngle - startAngle > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ",1 " + x2 + "," + y2 + " z";

            arc = paper.path(d);
            arc.attr("fill", color[i]);
            arc.attr("title", "Valor: "+data[i]);
            efeitoHover(arc);//Aplica o efeito
        }
        //clear arrays
        data = [];
        color = [];
        sectorAngleArr = [];
    }
};
```

```css
#holder {
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js"></script>
<div id="holder"></div>
```

Comment: Uma boa seria tirar isso do hover e passar pro elemento em si: 
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
    transform-origin: center center; para da um efeito de transição tanto hover quanto mouseout....

Comment: @MatheusCristian tens razão rs, viajei. Editado

Comment: Obrigado, no chrome funciona perfeitamente, mas no firefox tem um pequeno problema. E queria que cada fatia ficasse por cima e nao por baixo. exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/tttxfvcu/15/

Comment: @akm Infelizmente o Raphael.js trabalha diferente em cada navegador, mas felizmente eles fornecem funções para dar compatibilidade, eu editei a resposta, veja o último exemplo.