# Como rotacionar imagem em divs

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma página com 3 divs. Uma delas recebe imagem sempre, gostaria que todas imagens ficassem nesta posição:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço isso no CSS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resolvi assim:

```
.vertical-img {
transform: rotate(90deg);
transform-origin: left top 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Utilize [*vendor prefixes*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3674/%C3%89-necess%C3%A1rio-adicionar-prefixos-em-algumas-propriedades-do-css) para maior compatibilidade da propriedade **transform**.

Segundo o [Can i use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), atualmente você precisa utilizar epenas *-webkit, -ms* e a propriedade propriamente dita.

Exemplo:

```css
.vertical-img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="" alt="Desc Imagem" class="vertical-img">
```

Answer (score -1):

só colocar dessa forma no seu Style que funciona,

```
.vertical-img {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

mais pra garantir que vai funcionar em todos os navegadores use os assim:

```
.vertical-img {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
```

Comment: Qual o propósito da sua resposta