# Rotacionar imagem CSS3 ou JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css3, react

Como consigo saber eu tenho que rotacionar uma imagem para exibir ela em uma pagina?

Eu consigo verificar isso no css ou tem que ser no javascript?

É que em dashboard de um site que eu desenvolvi a imagem aparece de cabeça para baixo na hora do upload, se eu abro esta imagem no windows 10 ela aparece certa mais se eu abro no windows 7 ele aparece de cabeça para baixo.

Então pensei em antes de mostra a imagem na pagina verificar se ela está na rotação e certa e se preciso rotacionar ela em 90º.

Utilizo React desse dasboard, então a solução tem que ser no css/html ou no javascript.

Comment: Não entendi direito o seu problema. Você quer detectar a direção da imagem e salvá-la de cabeça para baixo no upload ou exibi-la em Javascript e CSS de cabeça para baixo? De qualquer forma, isso me parece ser um [**problema XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). O problema real acho que é o de você estar recebendo imagens que estão de cabeça para baixo por algum motivo.

Comment: Na verdade eu quero deixar a imagem na rotação certa e não de cabeça para baixo. Eu preciso exibir ela na pagina na rotação certa, mesmo que ela esteja na rotação errada ou seja se ela esta de cabeça para baixo eu preciso exibir ela na tela corretamente.

Comment: Como você consegue determinar se uma imagem está certa, de cabeça para baixo ou de lado?

Comment: Só pra constar, recomendo a leitura do [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy), além de divertida é esclarecedora. (água de coco com tanque de guerra)

Comment: Talvez eu não tenho sido muito claro na minha pergunta, mais são fotos com pessoas quando eu faço o upload delas as pessoas ficam de cabeça para baixo, seu eu tentar fazer upload aqui no forum as pessoas vão estar de cabeça para baixo, mais quando eu abro as fotos no windows com o visualizador de imagens ela esta certa. O que eu quero saber é se tem como rotacionar essas fotos ao exibir elas na tela.

Comment: Seu problema não é o upload então ? Pq se faz o upload da imagem certa e depois ela fica errada, não precisa rotacionar e sim descobrir o pq dela estar virando. Entende ?

Comment: Você pode fazer isso com CSS, com esse link aqui você vai conseguir entender melhor: [Como rotacionar imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92678/como-rotacionar-imagem-em-divs/92682) Mas o ideal seria resolver o problema do porquê as imagens estão vindo de cabeça para baixo, e assim, ajustá-las. Abra um programa de edição como o Photoshop com a imagem desejada, e salve para web.
Para entender melhor, veja o que está nesse link aqui: [Por que minhas fotos estão aparecendo viradas após o Upload](https://www.villehost.com.br/whmcs/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase/336/Por-que-minhas-fotos-est

Comment: Caro @user7726 recomendo isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/170492/3635