# css - always define standard rule 'keyframe' when defining keyframe Error

Tags: css, css3, navegador-de-internet, webkit, keyframes

Estou recebendo erro no código abaixo que diz

> css -  always define standard rule 'keyframe' when defining keyframe   Error

Ele é executado normalmente no Chrome, mas não está funcionando no IE 11

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é que vc está declarando a animação apenas para o *vendor* prefix `-webkit-` que o Chrome entende mais o IE não.

Animação funcionando no IE11

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para corrigis basta vc adicionar o mesmo CSS porém sem o prefixo `@keyframes fadeIn {}`

**Veja que vai funcionar ai agora sem erro, esse é o código referente a imagem acima**

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    animation: fadeIn 1s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

**Dica**

Nessa pergunta tem detalhes que vão te interessar [É necessário adicionar prefixos em algumas propriedades do CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3674/%C3%89-necess%C3%A1rio-adicionar-prefixos-em-algumas-propriedades-do-css)

Comment: Correto. 
Basta remover a definição do motor webkit que funcionou.

Thank You!

Comment: @RafaelPatriciodaCruz na verdade se vc quiser garantir que os browsers mais antigos vão reconhecer a propriedade seria interessante manter os dois `@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { } ` e `@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { }` e se vc quiser ir além ainda pode se resguardar para o FireFox antigo usando `@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { }` (moz = mozilla)

Comment: Verdade. Super importante abordar outros navegadores para mitigar possíveis falhas de compatibilidade  ;)